# Erro na hora de debugar o programa: "No symbol table loaded"

Tags: c, debug

Ao debugar o programa aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10.1
>   Starting the debuggee failed: No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>   Debugger finished with status 0

Esse problema ocorre somente nesse projeto. Alguma solução para esse problema?

Comment: Com que comando esse projeto foi compilado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem diz para você utilizar o comando "file" para carregar o arquivo.

```
(gdb) exec-file test
(gdb) b 2
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) file test
Reading symbols from /home/user/test/test...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ea: file test.c, line 2.
(gdb)
```

Você pode tentar também passar o programa na linha de comando

```
$ gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[...]
Reading symbols from /home/user/test/test...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ea: file test.c, line 2.
(gdb)
```